# Can I draw a TBitmap without calls to winapi?

Tags: delphi, bitmap

When drawing a line on a TCanvas, you make two calls to a windows API : MoveTo and LineTo. The call to LineTo is extremely resource-intensive and I'm wondering if there is a better API to create bitmaps in Delphi.

Comment: (1) Use scanlines. There are hundreds of examples of this on the WWW and on Stack Overflow. (2) Use your own custom bitmap data structure (like `array of TColor` in row-major order) and only convert to/from Win32 bitmaps when you need to load/save/communicate bitmap data with the outside world.

Comment: How `draw a bitmap` is related to line drawing? Is cost of LineTo really large for you?

Comment: @MBo: if you have an algorithm that draws a bitmap by drawing N lines, where N ~ 10^6 or more, it will indeed be extremely slow. More often you draw a bitmap by assigning individual pixel values, and then again you'll find that `TBitmap.Pixels[X, Y]` is extremely slow, and the solution is the same: (1) use scanlines or (2) use your own pixel data buffer.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand I know about Pixels, but... do you think that scanline usage is much faster than LineTo call?

Comment: It's slow because I'm drawing a bunch of dashed lines, where the dashes have sizes that can't be replicated with pen style. So that's like, thousands of calls. @AndreasRejbrand Thanks for the tip ! Does Scanline return a pointer to the current row in the Canvas or are those completely separated ?

Comment: Each scanline is a row in the bitmap.

Comment: Yes, `LineTo`, `Pixels`, `Ellipse`, ... are all very slow. If you need performance, you must abandon the `TCanvas` methods and use either (1) scanlines or (2) custom data buffer.

Comment: `can't be replicated with pen style` What about ExtCreatePen with PS_USERSTYLE?

Comment: Other options: Abandon GDI and use GDI+, Direct2D, or OpenGL.

Comment: [Graphics32](https://github.com/graphics32) is an option

Comment: regarding the use of Scanline: A call to that method is also very costly, so keep that value in a local variable rather than getting it every time you need it.